# Как убрать отуступ между nav и content?

Tags: html, css3, html5

Пишу сайт и столкнулся с проблемами.  Вот код(слайдер работает, но не на codepen ):[Ссылка](https://codepen.io/roma321/pen/EbqzPo)

```
(Между nav и content большой отступ)
```

1-ая проблема: Как растянуть nav на всю страницу(ширину. width:100% не помогает)?( На данный момент занято не все место)
2-ая проблема :  Есть отступ между nav и content. Как его убрать?

```js
var slideNow = 1;
var slideCount = $('#slidewrapper').children().length;
var slideInterval = 3000;
var navBtnId = 0;
var translateWidth = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {
  var switchInterval = setInterval(nextSlide, slideInterval);

  $('#viewport').hover(function() {
    clearInterval(switchInterval);
  }, function() {
    switchInterval = setInterval(nextSlide, slideInterval);
  });

  $('#next-btn').click(function() {
    nextSlide();
  });

  $('#prev-btn').click(function() {
    prevSlide();
  });

  $('.slide-nav-btn').click(function() {
    navBtnId = $(this).index();

    if (navBtnId + 1 != slideNow) {
      translateWidth = -$('#viewport').width() * (navBtnId);
      $('#slidewrapper').css({
        'transform': 'translate(' + translateWidth + 'px, 0)',
        '-webkit-transform': 'translate(' + translateWidth + 'px, 0)',
        '-ms-transform': 'translate(' + translateWidth + 'px, 0)',
      });
      slideNow = navBtnId + 1;
    }
  });
});


function nextSlide() {
  if (slideNow == slideCount || slideNow <= 0 || slideNow > slideCount) {
    $('#slidewrapper').css('transform', 'translate(0, 0)');
    slideNow = 1;
  } else {
    translateWidth = -$('#viewport').width() * (slideNow);
    $('#slidewrapper').css({
      'transform': 'translate(' + translateWidth + 'px, 0)',
      '-webkit-transform': 'translate(' + translateWidth + 'px, 0)',
      '-ms-transform': 'translate(' + translateWidth + 'px, 0)',
    });
    slideNow++;
  }
}

function prevSlide() {
  if (slideNow == 1 || slideNow <= 0 || slideNow > slideCount) {
    translateWidth = -$('#viewport').width() * (slideCount - 1);
    $('#slidewrapper').css({
      'transform': 'translate(' + translateWidth + 'px, 0)',
      '-webkit-transform': 'translate(' + translateWidth + 'px, 0)',
      '-ms-transform': 'translate(' + translateWidth + 'px, 0)',
    });
    slideNow = slideCount;
  } else {
    translateWidth = -$('#viewport').width() * (slideNow - 2);
    $('#slidewrapper').css({
      'transform': 'translate(' + translateWidth + 'px, 0)',
      '-webkit-transform': 'translate(' + translateWidth + 'px, 0)',
      '-ms-transform': 'translate(' + translateWidth + 'px, 0)',
    });
    slideNow--;
  }
}
```

```css
/* This is a Header*/

body {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/*This is a navbar*/

#nav {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 0 3em 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #2b3030;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}

#nav li {
  float: left;
}

#nav li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px calc(100%/7);
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}

#nav li a:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: #12700c;
}


/*Content*/


/* This is a slider  */

#block-for-slider {
  width: 1280px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

#viewport {
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

#slidewrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: calc(100% * 4);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-transition: 1s;
  -o-transition: 1s;
  transition: 1s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -o-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

#slidewrapper ul,
#slidewrapper li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#slidewrapper li {
  width: calc(100%/4);
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
  float: left;
}

.slide-img {
  width: 100%;
}

#prev-btn,
#next-btn {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: calc(50% - 25px);
}

#prev-btn:hover,
#next-btn:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#prev-btn {
  left: 20px;
}

#next-btn {
  right: 20px;
}

#nav-btns {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 20px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.slide-nav-btn {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 3px;
}

.slide-nav-btn:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav">
  <ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#">Lalala</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Lalala</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Lalala</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Lalala</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Lalala</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Lalala</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Lalala</a></li>
  </ul>

</div>

</div>
<div class="content">

  <div id="block-for-slider">
    <div id="viewport">
      <ul id="slidewrapper">
        <li class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/1280x250" alt="" class="slide-image"></li>
        <li class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/1280x250" alt="" class="slide-image"></li>
        <li class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/1280x250" alt="" class="slide-image"> </li>
        <li class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/1280x250" alt="" class="slide-image"></li>
      </ul>

      <div id="prev-next-btns">
        <div id="prev-btn"></div>
        <div id="next-btn"></div>
      </div>
      <ul id="nav-btns">
        <li class="slide-nav-btn"></li>
        <li class="slide-nav-btn"></li>
        <li class="slide-nav-btn"></li>
        <li class="slide-nav-btn"></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых начнем с того, что в CODEPEN у тебя не работало, потому, что JQ не подключил. Во-вторых, между nav и content нет ни каких отступов. Сейчас у тебя 
content зеленого цвета, а в третьих что бы что то растянуть на всю шинину, не надо забывать о родителях...  У тебя есть блок

```
<div id="block-for-slider">
```

у него родитель

```
<div class="content">
```

содержимому ты стили задал а родителю нет... Вопрос, почему?  Тоже самое и с меню у тебя...   Я  добавил стили, так на угад, я не знаю твоих планов, просто, чтобы показать как он выгладит на самом деле и где находиться...

```js
var slideNow = 1;
var slideCount = $('#slidewrapper').children().length;
var slideInterval = 3000;
var navBtnId = 0;
var translateWidth = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {
  var switchInterval = setInterval(nextSlide, slideInterval);

  $('#viewport').hover(function() {
    clearInterval(switchInterval);
  }, function() {
    switchInterval = setInterval(nextSlide, slideInterval);
  });

  $('#next-btn').click(function() {
    nextSlide();
  });

  $('#prev-btn').click(function() {
    prevSlide();
  });

  $('.slide-nav-btn').click(function() {
    navBtnId = $(this).index();

    if (navBtnId + 1 != slideNow) {
      translateWidth = -$('#viewport').width() * (navBtnId);
      $('#slidewrapper').css({
        'transform': 'translate(' + translateWidth + 'px, 0)',
        '-webkit-transform': 'translate(' + translateWidth + 'px, 0)',
        '-ms-transform': 'translate(' + translateWidth + 'px, 0)',
      });
      slideNow = navBtnId + 1;
    }
  });
});


function nextSlide() {
  if (slideNow == slideCount || slideNow <= 0 || slideNow > slideCount) {
    $('#slidewrapper').css('transform', 'translate(0, 0)');
    slideNow = 1;
  } else {
    translateWidth = -$('#viewport').width() * (slideNow);
    $('#slidewrapper').css({
      'transform': 'translate(' + translateWidth + 'px, 0)',
      '-webkit-transform': 'translate(' + translateWidth + 'px, 0)',
      '-ms-transform': 'translate(' + translateWidth + 'px, 0)',
    });
    slideNow++;
  }
}

function prevSlide() {
  if (slideNow == 1 || slideNow <= 0 || slideNow > slideCount) {
    translateWidth = -$('#viewport').width() * (slideCount - 1);
    $('#slidewrapper').css({
      'transform': 'translate(' + translateWidth + 'px, 0)',
      '-webkit-transform': 'translate(' + translateWidth + 'px, 0)',
      '-ms-transform': 'translate(' + translateWidth + 'px, 0)',
    });
    slideNow = slideCount;
  } else {
    translateWidth = -$('#viewport').width() * (slideNow - 2);
    $('#slidewrapper').css({
      'transform': 'translate(' + translateWidth + 'px, 0)',
      '-webkit-transform': 'translate(' + translateWidth + 'px, 0)',
      '-ms-transform': 'translate(' + translateWidth + 'px, 0)',
    });
    slideNow--;
  }
}
```

```css
body {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}




/*This is a navbar*/

#nav {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 3em 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    list-style: none;

    background-color: #2b3030;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}

#nav ul {

    width: 100%;
}

#nav li {
    float: left;
    width: 14%;
}

#nav li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px calc(100%/7);
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}

#nav li a:hover {
    color: white;
    background-color: #12700c;
}





/*Content*/


/* This is a slider  */

#block-for-slider {
    width: 1280px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 100px;
}

#viewport {
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

#slidewrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: calc(100% * 4);
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-transition: 1s;
    -o-transition: 1s;
    transition: 1s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -o-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

#slidewrapper ul,
#slidewrapper li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#slidewrapper li {
    width: calc(100%/4);
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
}

.slide-img {
    width: 100%;
}

#prev-btn,
#next-btn {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    top: calc(50% - 25px);
}

#prev-btn:hover,
#next-btn:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

#prev-btn {
    left: 20px;
}

#next-btn {
    right: 20px;
}

#nav-btns {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 20px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.slide-nav-btn {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 3px;
}

.slide-nav-btn:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav">
  <ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#">Lalala</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Lalala</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Lalala</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Lalala</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Lalala</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Lalala</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Lalala</a></li>
  </ul>

</div>

<div class="content">

  <div id="block-for-slider">
    <div id="viewport">
      <ul id="slidewrapper">
        <li class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/1280x250" alt="" class="slide-image"></li>
        <li class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/1280x250" alt="" class="slide-image"></li>
        <li class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/1280x250" alt="" class="slide-image"> </li>
        <li class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/1280x250" alt="" class="slide-image"></li>
      </ul>

      <div id="prev-next-btns">
        <div id="prev-btn"></div>
        <div id="next-btn"></div>
      </div>
      <ul id="nav-btns">
        <li class="slide-nav-btn"></li>
        <li class="slide-nav-btn"></li>
        <li class="slide-nav-btn"></li>
        <li class="slide-nav-btn"></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```